# php and js response between each other

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

For example: there is a form and you need to show some interactive UI which depends on the result php returns. I have an input field and there are some validation. Field must be not empty and so on. Using only php or js its easy. Since im using laravel framework it has built in validation. But if I want to make jquery work to corresponding feedback of server side, like change color of the input field and so on, is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[AJAX.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) The client-side JavaScript should make an asynchronous request to some PHP script from your server, and then do something based on the response.